# Clear "dataSource" for UISearchDisplayController

Tags: iphone, web-services, uitableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I am using an UISearchDisplayController together with a web service. I want to clear the NSArray that holds my results every time the text field of the search bar is clear, but I didn't find any method that gets called in the UISearchDisplayDelegate when the text is clear.

Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: can u plz elaborate ur question little bit more

Comment: I want to call a method every time the text from the search bar gets cleared.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following methods:

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString;
```

Comment: This method doesn't get called when you clear the text in the search bar.